# <ul> and <ol> Display Issue - Different Indendation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display an unordered list like this:

```
<p style="margin-top:1em; line-height: 1.4;">Dear John,</p>

<p style="margin-top:1em; line-height: 1.4;">Here's the list of items to collect:</p>

<p style="margin-top:1em; line-height: 1.4;"></p>

<ul>
<li>Item 1 - Apples</li>
<li>Item 2 - Bananas</li>
</ul>
```

which appears like this:

[image]

If I change this to an ordered list it appears like this:

[image]

I can't get the unordered list to indent in the same way as the ordered list. Here's the relevant part of the CSS:

```
    html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, li{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body{
        font-family: 'Myriad Set', 'Myriad Pro', 'Myriad', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        max-width: 775px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 1.25em 0 0;
        font-size: 12pt;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
    }
```

Comment: For `ul`, you have zero padding and margin, but not for `ol` in your css. So just add `ol` to the first line of your shared css code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other answers - I assumed you wanted to remove the margin and padding on the ul - but then re-reading your post - it seem you want the ul to be indented relative to the rest of the text - I have it indented 1em - but you can change that.

I would also suggest CSS counters (which would automatically number the items in the list and prevent you from having to manually add "item 1 ... item2...etc)- but to keep it in line with what you have - remove the bullet points and set margin-left on the ul to 1em.

```css
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    
  body{
      font-family: 'Myriad Set', 'Myriad Pro', 'Myriad', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      max-width: 775px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 1.25em 0 0;
      font-size: 12pt;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #000;
  }
  
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-left: 0;
}

p {
  margin-top:1em;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

a {
  color: #58aefe;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p>Dear John,</p>

<p>Here's the list of items to collect:</p>


<ul>
  <li>Item 1 - Apples</li>
  <li>Item 2 - Bananas</li>
</ul>

<p>If you have any questions please contact the Warehouse at <a href="#">warehouse@acme.com</a></p>
<p>Thanks</p>
<p>Acme fruit suppliers</p>
```